# Длины сторон треугольника вводятся с клавиатуры

Tags: pascalabc.net

Длины сторон треугольника вводятся с клавиатуры. Нужно вывести "существует" если такой треугольник может существовать, если не может вывести "не существует". Решить через case of.

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: Так C# или Паскаль?

Comment: Лучше Паскаль :)

Comment: Нужно именно через case of сделать, и я не представляю как это сделать.

Comment: case of (a + b > c) and (b + c > a) and (c + a > b)  true: WriteLn("Exists"); false:WriteLn("Does not exists");  end;

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Pipok - Неужели это то, что имелось в виду в задании? Я это написал с изрядной долей сарказма.

Answer (score 1):

Проверка на самом деле очень простая: треугольник со сторонами `a`, `b` и `c` существует тогда и только тогда, когда длины положительны и выполняется неравенство треугольника:

```
a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && a + b > c && b + c > a && c + a > b
```

Ввод чисел с консоли в переменные и вывод результата, думаю, вы уж организуете сами.

---

Обновление: как правильно подсказывает @Igor в комментарии, проверки на неотрицательность не нужны, так как они следуют из неравенства треугольника. Действительно, если `a + b > c` и `c + a > b`, складывая, получим `2a + b + c > b + c`, то есть `2a > 0`. Таким образом, достаточно проверить просто

```
a + b > c && b + c > a && c + a > b
```

Comment: Благодарю, но нужно через case of )

Comment: `a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0` - не нужны

Comment: @Igor: Точно, спасибо! Обновил ответ.

Comment: @Pipok а что, case of с булевым типом уже не работает?..